# File Status Highlights not working properly in PhpStorm 8.0.2

Tags: git, phpstorm

All files in my php project are added to the local git repo and committed properly, yet **PhpStorm colors them brown**, [meaning](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/file-status-highlights.html) "**File exists locally, but is not in the repository, and is not scheduled for adding.**". This is clearly wrong.

All other project are fine.

This might be rated as "merely annoying", but I like the coloring feature a lot, and I have not the slightest idea what could cause this.

Any hint?

Comment: I know this doesn't help you but maintaining a correct state of the repo seems to be a common problem for tools built on top of the truth (i.e. command line). TortoiseGit almost always displays a wrong state of the repo which is quite confusing. Best would be to turn off the disturbing stuff and rely on the console for receiving a correct state of your repo.

Comment: @eckes - yeah, too bad, isn't it? But in this case, it works so well for other projects, so I figured it is worth a try to fix this.